# how to open chrome to get some text box values from postman?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, postman, postman-testcase

I am running API1 from postman but to run API2, would need to pass some values from API1 response to UI page & post submitting it there in UI, need to capture the value from UI text box and pass it to API2 request in postman.

So to do that, how to launch Chrome browser from postman ?

Comment: Please share the code, what you have tried?

Comment: Hello, I am actually a newbie for coding & postman as well. So haven't tried coding as such.

Answer (score 0):

1. using JMeter recorder, try to record all the interactions in the browser.
2. use the json extractor(or any other extractor based on the response) to extract API response and
3. Pass the same in the API2